# Water is warm, glacial would

Tags: grammar

If the temperature of the sea water is warm, glacials would melt.

I know people use "was" instead "is", but here I am talking about a fact and the hypothetical result of it. Don't you think "is" makes sense?

Comment: If it *were* warm, glaciers *would* melt. / If it *is* warm, glaciers *will* melt. If you're talking about a fact why do you start with "if"?

Comment: By the way, is it 'glacials' or 'glaciers'?  1) If the temperature of the sea water is warm, glaciers will melt. 2) .....was warm,....glaciers would melt. As a statement of fact, 1) seems to be ideal.